# Java: How can I add a name to a rectangle which is a node of a graph?

Tags: java, awt

I'm new in java and I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

This is what I have to do:

[image: todo]

From what I've seen, a Rectangle made with java.awt.Rectangle has an x and y coordinates and a width and height. So, I can create a Rectangle like that (for example):

```
Rectangle node = new Rectangle (5,10,15,20);
```

However, **I'm not sure how can I add a name to that rectangle**. So far I've created a Node class like that:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Node {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private String name;

    public Node(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if that's correct since from my understanding the Rectangle object already has 4 of the 5 parameters in my constructor for a node. So what is the right way of doing it? Should I make a parent class for a rectangle and then a node subclass where I just add a name in the constructor? Hope that was clear enough, I'm really confused... thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is already looking good. For what I understand:

A node has a Rectangle and a Name.

So your class members should be:

```
public class Node{
    private String name;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    ... 
}
```

by keeping the same constructor signature you can initialise these two members `name` and `rectangle`.

For the third point you need to have a second constructor with no parameters that initialises the name  and the rectangle by default. 
The default constructor looks like this:

```
public Node(){
      ...
}
```

**EDIT** (to answer your comment)

Almost :) It is not very clear to me if you have to pass a rectangle in your constructor or more like position and size. If it where up to me, I implemented both of them.

```
public class Node{

    private String name;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public Node(){
        this.name = "some default name";
        this.rectangle = // however you initialise your default rectangle
    }

   public Node(String name, int x, int y, int width, int height){
       this.name = name;
       this.rectangle = .... // use x,y, width and height to create a new rectangle
   }

   // your solution:
   public Node(String name, Rectangle rectangle){
       this.name = name;
       this.rectangle = rectangle;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if I properly understood that so, should my code look like that?
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Node {
    private String name;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public Node(Rectangle rectangle, String name) {
        this.rectangle=rectangle;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Node() {
        this.rectangle=rectangle;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

(I'm not sure how to show code in a comment, I'm kinda new to stack overflow, sorry)